# Is there a quick way to convert Latex table to MS word/power point table?

Tags: conversion

There's a lot of data in these tables and I really do not want to copy paste it for a presentation. Can we somehow convert them to MS word tables?

Comment: not in general, if it is mostly data you can simply edit `&` to `,` and make a csv file to pass to excel or word. If you have lots of column spans or tex formatting then it ... depends..

Comment: Open the pdf file (from LaTeX)  with ms word. (I am using 2013) You will be surprised!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what the contents of your table are (text? numbers? is it formatted with tabs or spaces to make to code look good?), but I would copy/paste the table in Excel.
I would then use the "Text to Columns" tool under the "Data" tab and specify `&` as field separator.
Having the table correctly formatted in Excel should make it easy to import it in Word or Powerpoint.

Comment: Numbers and text, mostly numbers though.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? Did it work?

Comment: yes it was one of the better ones

Answer (score 2):

I believe that opening your pdf with Word and having it auto convert the pdf into a readable word document is the fastest and easiest method for converting a LaTeX table into a word or powerpoint table.
However, for completeness an alternative method is: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/.
Go to File>From LaTeX code

[image]

Then paste your Latex Code:

[image]

Then, copy paste the table it creates into word or powerpoint and format as needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is 2024, I am writing to provide an alternative solution.

We all know Word sucks at processing Latex, as many other typesetting software do. But, there exists one thing that turns out to be everyone's love, and that would be HTML.

So instead of making Latex tables into Word tables, what we need to do is convert latex to HTML and just copy and paste. And that opens up a lot of possibilities.

Apparently, there exists a great deal of Latex2HTML tools.
I used `Tex4ebook` (which is included in Tex Live Distribution, I believe.) to convert my Tex file to an HTML webpage.

Reminder:
**Keep your tex file as simple as possible.**
Bc `Tex4ebook` is not an omni-all-latex-handler, a `multirow` or a `\bm` environment is enough to break it, so just keep it simple.
Consider creating a new tex file for table-converting purposes.

Otherwise, you may get errors such as:
`Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 5`
that you may not have any f███ing clue about.

For example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tabular}{|c | c c c c|}
        Method         & Training Mode       & Dice                  & IoU                   & PA                              
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It seems `latexml` would be a better option for creating HTML, but I just don't have the time to test it out. I hope they provide binary directly.

Comment: There is an opportunity for someone in the community to provide a nice new showcase service for LaTeXML. I had made one way back (and it shows its age), but you could still quickly try small examples with it at:

https://latexml.mathweb.org/editor

Your tabular above seems to convert well I think.